# DHTMLX gantt chart hide parent tasks how?

Tags: dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

In DHTMLX Gantt chart

I need to show all hierarchy structure tasks in left panel like

1. Parent
   1.1 SubParent
   1.1.1 Tasks

But Right side panel i need to show only child tasks not parent and subparent.

You can  refer below screen shot'[image]

**Reference Link : https://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGantt/02_features.html**

**Need:** 
1. I need to hide strategic Definition and Obtain/create... right side blue bar only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use [task_class template](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_task_class_template.html) to specify the CSS class that will be applied to task bars with children to hide them

and [getChildren](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/api__gantt_getchildren.html) method to check if the target task has got the 1st-level child tasks:

```
gantt.templates.task_class = function(start, end, task){
  var children = gantt.getChildren(task.id);
  if(children.length)
    return "hideTask";

  return "";
};
```

CSS:

```
.hideTask{visibility: hidden;}
```

[Demo](http://snippet.dhtmlx.com/ed5c1782d)